# Python: How can I rename a dictionary item and still use it as case statement option?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am using a dictionary as a case statement in my application. I have the need to rename a dictionary item but still use the dictionary as a case statement. To illustrate what I am trying to do I create this example.

```
def venus():
    print 'Venus'

def mars():
    print 'Mars'

def earth():
    print 'Earth'

def pluto():
    print 'Pluto'

options = { '1': venus, '2': mars, '3': earth}

options['1']()
options['2']()
options['3']()

options['1'] = 'pluto'

options['1']()
```

If you run it will print out the following:

```
Venus
Mars
Earth
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dict.py", line 22, in <module>
    options['1']()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Before you ask, no I cannot just add another entry to the dictionary to catch the Pluto option.

How can I rename a dictionary item and still use it as case statement option?

Comment: You are not renaming anything; you are *assigning a string*. Did you mean to assign the `pluto` **function** instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't pass it in as a string.  You need to change the dictionary reference to the object `pluto` which is your function... not the `string` `'pluto'`

```
options['1'] = pluto
```

Comment: duh! I thought I tried that.  Let me check something. I thought there was  a reason it did not work....

Comment: Maybe you had tried to assign it `pluto()`. That would have made `options['1']` refer to what the function `pluto` returns, which in your case is an implicit `None`.

Comment: Well, it is working so thanks.  Maybe I had a space it in or something odd.  I will mark this as the answer.  thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you wrapping function `pluto` inside the string?

Just do what you did when defining the dictionary

```
options['1'] = pluto #assign the function directly
options['1']() # prints Pluto
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a function that returns `"pluto"`.

```
options['1'] = lambda: "pluto"
```

Or you can define a function that turns a string into a function

```
def to_func(s):
    return (lambda: s)

options['1'] = to_func("pluto")
```